# How to avoid jQuery when using Collapse plugin in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: jquery, performance, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The problem overview is simple, I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I want strictly the components and plugins that I'm using.

**Performance is a critical feature in this project.**

With the `navbar` component I want to use the [collapsible](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) functionality to trigger mobile devices too. I **only** need that feature.

The Official Bootstrap docs say explicitly:

> Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files)

The [collape.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js) plugin only has 4.84 kb of size.

The dependency [transition.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js) only has 1.544 kb of size.

I'm a bit concerned by the fact that for this specific project it is kinda overkill to include jQuery only to allow this "basic" feature.

So far I have these possible solutions:

- **Bootstrap without jQuery alternatives:** I saw [some projects](https://github.com/tagawa/bootstrap-without-jquery/) that trigger this exact issue but my main complaint is the lack of support. The project mentioned has actually more than 9 month without a single commit (at least in the master branch). **Edit:** In fact after trying a little, this option doesn't seem to work with Boostrap 3.
- **Manually rewrites:** A rewrite of the functionality to eliminate the jQuery dependency of the plugin seems a little overkill too.
- **Use jQuery specific modules:** The jQuery project claims that special builds can be created that exclude subsets of jQuery functionality. This seems the right path but again, I don't now exactly which subsets of jQuery are essentials to support the collapse plugin.

Again, the problem is exactly that:

How do I avoid jQuery when using **Collapse** plugin in Bootstrap 3?

### Edits:

- **Codepen:** I crated a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nGuEi) isolating the scenario.
- **Zepto:** The `zepto.js` library doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using http://zeptojs.com/ instead. It's billed a semi-replacement to jQuery and it smaller. You can also do custom builds if you want to just target the specific jQuery-like features you need to support the other libraries.

Comment: ZeptoJS doesn't seems to work, i tested that locally and create a codepen. Question edited to reflect feedback.